# Какие файлы и папки не нужно ставить на отслеживание в проекте Intelij IDEA(Java) для Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Какие файлы и папки не нужно ставить на отслеживание в проекте Intelij IDEA(Java) для Git?
Знаю, что папку idea ненужно отслеживать, есть ли еще?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, исправил.

Comment: какой тип проекта?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, maven

Comment: @Kromster годная правка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стоит добавить в `.gitignore`:

- директорию `.idea/`
- файл проекта - файл с расширением `.iml`
- директорию куда попадают скомпилированные/сгенерированные артефакты (зависит от проекта), для **maven** - это `target/`

Простым вариантом будет добавить эти исключения в глобальный `.gitignore` и это избавит от необходимости добавлять их в каждый проект.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кому-то пригодится, для инициализации файла `.gitignore` можно использовать [сервис-генератор](https://www.gitignore.io/).

Есть возможность задания:

- используемую IDE
- языка проекта
- операционной системы
- используемых фреймворков

Удобно использовать при старте проекта.